# PhpStorm opens new editor when debbuging a php page

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PhpStorm with a local Apache2 and Xdebug. Everything seems to work well but when I debug a page and the code reaches a breakpoint, PhpStorm opens a new editor tab with the code of the php page.

[image: multiple copy of the php page during debug in PhpStorm]

How can I avoid this behavior?

Thank you,

Comment: From what I see from your screenshot -- it opens you the actual **compiled Blade template** -- seems logical. Although it should be able to debug the actual template.... Have a look at what you may be missing (the "Enable Blade debugging" section) -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/laravel.html#debugging-blade-templates

Comment: Same for smarty or twig templates. They are compiled into PHP to debug into.